# Simplifying VCL thread wrapper code

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, c++builder, vcl

I am using thread wrapper which checks if function which updates VCL (which also has some arguments) was called from main thread or not and then executes in within the context of Main thread always.

It works but I want to make it simpler. The problem is that I have to repeat this code in every function which needs VCL synchronization which is prone to errors. Is there a way to make this wrapper simpler and more re-useable? Note that this particular wrapper only uses one parameter but there can be any number of parameters which are copied to `TLocalArgs` and passed on.

Current code:

```
boost::scoped_ptr<TIdThreadComponent> WorkerThread;

...

void TForm1::SetMemoMessage(UnicodeString Msg)
{
// Check which thread called function, main thread or worker thread
if (GetCurrentThreadId() != System::MainThreadID)
    {
    struct TLocalArgs
        {
        TForm1 *Form;
        UnicodeString Msg;
        void __fastcall SetMemoMessage() // Same name as main function to make it easier to maintain
            {
            // We are in main thread now, safe to call message update directly
            Form->SetMemoMessage(Msg);
            }
        };

    // We are in worker thread, wrap into Synchronize
    TLocalArgs Args = { this, Msg };
    WorkerThread->Synchronize(&Args.SetMemoMessage);
    return;
    }

// MAIN THREAD CODE is very simple compared to wrapper above
Memo1->Text = Msg;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TThread::Synchronize()` checks `MainThreadID` internally for you and calls the specified procedure directly if `Synchronize()` is called from the main thread.  So just call `Synchronize()` unconditionally and let it handle the details.  `Synchronize()` also has overloaded static versions available so you don't even need a `TThread` pointer to call it.

Try this:

```
void TForm1::SetMemoMessage(UnicodeString Msg)
{
    struct TLocalArgs
    {
        UnicodeString Msg;
        void __fastcall SetMemoMessage()
        {
            Form1->Memo1->Text = Msg;
        }
    };

    TLocalArgs Args;
    Args.Msg = Msg;
    TThread::Synchronize(NULL, &Args.SetMemoMessage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely an improvement over my version.

Comment: does not work in Builder C++ 6 `[C++ Error] main.cpp(100): E2247 '_fastcall TThread::Synchronize(void (_fastcall * (_closure )())())' is not accessible`

Comment: @AndreiKrasutski correct, the `static` overload of `Synchronize()` was added in Delphi 7 (so, it didn't appear in C++Builder until BDS 2006) and the non-static overload was `protected` in C++Builder 6 and only usable inside a `TThread` derived class. The code in question is using `UnicodeString`, thus RADStudio 2009 or later, where the non-static overload is `public`